# Get IP address of Wi-Fi network requiring sign-in

Tags: android, android-wifi

When connected via wifi our app pings a server script and the server grabs the IP address. Easy. But when the wi-fi network requires sign in, the android phone only partially connects to the wifi and maintains the connection via 3g/4g. Therefore the script is pinged by the mobile network and not the wifi network. Is it possible to get the external IP address of the wi-fi network that requires a sign in from the Android device itself?

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way for you to know the external IP is to ping your server. You're not connected to the Wifi, so you can't use the internet connection, so you cannot ping the server.

This applies to all wifi connections, not only on android. Wifi as technology has nothing to do with the external IP of the router.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using an API like [IP-API](http://ip-api.com/json). Just hit the API [URL](http://ip-api.com/json) and you would get a JSON response like following :

```
{
  "as": "Network Name",
  "city": "City Name",
  "country": "Country Name",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "isp": "ISP Name",
  "lat": 88.9999,
  "lon": 99.3686,
  "org": "Organization Name",
  "query": "8.8.8.8",
  "region": "TX",
  "regionName": "Tennessy",
  "status": "success",
  "timezone": "US",
  "zip": "12345"
}
```

Parse the JSON response and get the IP address using query tag.

Comment: IMO it returns my external IP address.